# Rails 4 ActionController::Metal with Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to use ActionController::Metal in a Rails 4 project to make an API "base" controller as follows:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::Serialization
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
end
```

I'm then inheriting from this in each of my API controllers, e.g.:

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/plans_controller.rb
class Api::V1::PlansController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    @plans = Plan.all

    if params[:ids]
      @plans = @plans.where(id: params[:ids])
    end
  end

  def show
    @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def plan_params
      params.require(:plan).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

I want to use `ActiveModel::Serializers` to generate the JSON responses for my API, I have created the following Serializer:

```
# app/serializers/plan_serializer.rb
class PlanSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

I currently get an `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` error when I try and load up my API endpoint (`/api/v1/plans.json`) - I think there is something missing from Metal which I need in order to use serializers, but I'm not sure what?!

Comment: Is your controller + serializer are working if you are trying to use ActionController::Metal ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifically render your template in the controller method. For example:

```
def show
  @plan = Plan.find(params[:id])
  render :show
end
```

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket.